# Does a smaller reflective box filled with trapped photons make the box heavier?

Tags: optics, photons, mass, reflection, mass-energy

In Leonard Susskind's video lecture on the Higgs Boson, he uses a model of a box made from very light, very reflective material containing photons, explaining how in this way, for example, the proton can get its mass. Would it be intuitive to think that a smaller container would make the box more massive due to more reflections?

Lecture, @ $40:14$

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqNg819PiZY&t=3267s

Answer (score 1):

Simply putting the photons in a smaller box does not change the gravitational mass of the box + photons, because the box will contain the same amount of energy.  This is not quite true, because when the photons are closer together they have lower gravitational potential energy, so the overall energy is very slightly reduced.

On the other hand, putting the photons in a large box and then squeezing the box to make it smaller will raise the frequency of the photons and increase their energy, thereby increasing the gravitational mass of the box + photons.  Squeezing the box requires energy, which becomes added photon energy.

Comment: Can you please tell me "then squeezing the box to make it smaller will raise the frequency of the photons", what do you mean, how will the squeezing of the box raise the frequency of the photons?

Comment: If a photon bounces off a moving mirror, it gains energy.  It does not change speed.  The box would need to be lined with perfect mirrors.  As the box is being squeezed, the photons will gain energy with each reflection.  The energy gain results in a frequency increase.

Comment: Can you please tell me how a photon would gain energy bouncing off a moving mirror? In one direction, it would gain energy, but in the opposite it would lose?

Comment: That is correct: if the mirror is moving toward the photon source, the photon gains energy.  If the mirror is moving away from the photon source, the photon loses energy.  Think of the photon as a tennis ball and the mirror as a tennis racquet.

Comment: Yes, what I do not understand is, why the two do not net out to 0? Moving with gains, moving against loses.

Comment: The sides of the box move toward each other, always in the opposite direction to an approaching photon.  "Source" in this case is the *reflected image* of the source.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the reflections that make the box massive, it is the energy. If you put the same energy in a smaller box, the box isn't more massive.

Furthermore, it is not necessarily easy to describe what "a reflection" is in a small box, because radiation is a wave and does not undergo isolated reflection events, the way lots of fast bouncing balls in a box would. In a sense the radiation is being reflected all the time.

Comment: If gravitation is taken into account, N neutrons in a box have less energy when the box is smaller.  Not much less, but less.  Same is true for photons, as long as the photons have the same *locally measured* frequency.

Comment: Yes, I agree. My point was that the change in energy/mass isn't caused by "more reflections".

Comment: And you're right about that.